# Is it safe to use a lugnut with a different outer shank diameter?

Tags: wheels, lug-nut

I have an older care with one of the lug nuts missing and they are proving hard to find and exact replacement for. I picked up some lug-nuts that fit down snug but my concern is that the new lug nut has a shank with a slightly smaller outer diameter than the other lug-nuts.

As you can see in the photos the new lug nut bolt has the same size threads that go into the rotor but the threads are smaller on the nut side. The shank on the new lug-nut is also smaller by about a millimeter or so.

My main question is, is it unsafe to drive with a lug-nut that has a slightly smaller shank than the original nuts?

Related question, is it Ok to have one lug nut that's slightly different or should I change them all?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is NOT a good idea.... You must use the correct size/shank of wheel nuts for the type of wheels you're using. An ill fitting nut/nuts will loosen off as the vehicles wheel flexes under load. 
As a technician I have seen the severe damage to other peoples vehicles, and unfortunately the people themselves from wheel nuts that have come off whilst on the motorway.

Please use the correct wheel nuts.

Comment: Absolutely correct here, the outer shank diameter is crucial to stop the wheel rotating and becoming loose. While the idea of those new studs with nuts is fine, all the threads should match as another person may not notice until too late. The outer diameter issue rules out the use of the new ones.

Comment: Any nut is better than no nut at all, but only as an emergency measure.